# SQL Error while trying to extract nested json data

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, unnest

I am running an SQL query to extract nested JSON data.

```
SELECT watsonResponse.responseId,
       watsonResponse.chatId,
       d.*
FROM watson_response_table watsonResponse
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT d2.*
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(watsonResponse.watsonresponse_output) AS d(events)
             CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT d2.events ->> 'data'         AS watsonResponse_ouput_data
             , d2.events ->> 'text'         AS watsonResponse_output_text
             , d2.events ->> 'uiActionCode' AS watsonResponse_output_uiActionCode
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(d.events) AS d2(events)
        ) d2
    WHERE d.events ->> 'uiActionCode' = 'TextWithButton'
    ) d;
```

It fails with message **SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object**

I am using PostgresSQL 11+. Here is what the JSON looks like,

```
[
  {
    "text": [
      "Some text!"
    ],
    "uiActionCode": "textOnly"
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "type": "options",
      "options": [
        { "label": "test", "value": "testvalue" },
        { "label": "test2", "value": "testvalue2" },
        {
          "label": "test3",
          "value": "testQuestion?"
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": ["testQuestion2?"],
    "uiActionCode": "TextWithButton"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: I'm wondering why my SQL query is failing. The sql query should return successfully with the data in my SQL editor. It will have five columns (responseId, chatId, data, text, uiActionCode). Specifically, data column should have everything inside of data : {} ; text should have "testQuestion2" as the value in its column, and uiActionCode will have TextWithButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following this correctly, one level of unnesting is sufficient. You can then use the JSON accessors to get the results you want:

```
SELECT 
    r.responseId,
    r.chatId,
    d.events ->> 'uiActionCode' AS output_uiActionCode,
    d.events -> 'text' ->> 0    AS output_text,
    d.events -> 'data'          AS output_data,
FROM watson_response_table watsonResponse r
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(r.watsonresponse_output) AS d(events)
WHERE d.events ->> 'uiActionCode' = 'TextWithButton'
```

Note that there is an important difference between accessors `->` and `->>`. The former returns an object, while the latter returns a text value. You need to carefully pick the correct operator according to what needs to be done for each field.